# Problem with step in simplifying

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am working through a proof and have

```
x^2 + x
```

then my next step takes that and turns in to

```
(x^2 - x) + 2x
```

How did that step happen? Where does the 2x come from? Can someone explain, I'm confused on it.

Comment: $M = M + z - z$ always.  So $x^2 + x = x^2 + x - x + x = (x^2 - x) + x + x = (x^2-x) +2x$.  At this stage it's just shoving numbers about.  We can always shove numbers about.  Example we could have done $x^2 + x = e^{\ln(x^2 + x}$ because $M = e^{\ln M}$ always (if $M > 0$).  Shoving numbers doesn't mean anything deep... unless there is a destionation in mind.... which the author clearly does have.

Comment: Or more simply:  $(x^2 - x) + 2x = x^2 + 2x -x = x^2 + x$.

Comment: If $b = a+1$ then $1 = b-a$ and $x = bx - ax$ so $x^2 + x = (x^2 -ax) + bx$.  Always.  Now it might not be clear that $(x^2 -ax) + bx$ is any more *useful* than $x^2 + x$... but $(x^2 -ax) + bx$ *does* equal $x^2 + bx - ax = x^2 + x$.  That is undeniable.  So both the $a$ and the $b$ "came from" the fact that $1 = b-a$.  That's all.  the $2x$ and the $-x$ "came from" $1 = 2 - 1$.

Comment: To go from $x^2+x$ to $(x^2-x)+2x$ we simply add zero, or one of the many aliases of zero, i.e. $2x-2x$. This gives $$x^2+x=x^2+x+(2x-2x)=x^2+(x-2x)+2x=(x^2-x)+2x$$

Answer (score 1):

since $$x^2+x=x^2-x+x+x=x^2-x+2x$$

Comment: So if I was explain it outloud i would say I factored? Simplified?

Comment: Neither.  You shoved numbers about to get an equivalent statement.  You didn't simplify because the result is more *complicated*.  Solving equations you *usually* want to make things simpler.  But there's no law that says we can't make them more complicated.  Sometimes by making things complicated you will make things much more simpler *later*.

Answer (score 0):

You have $x=2x-x$, so $x^2+x=x^2+2x-x=x^2-x+2x=(x^2-x)+2x$